# Dynamic attribute and value save to database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a database table like :

id | title | Url

And i have a form like the screenshot...

[image]

i have tried like that

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control " style="border-radius: 0px;" placeholder="Tittle" id="slider" name="title[]">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" style="border-radius: 0px;" placeholder="Link" id="slider" name="url[]">
</div>
```

And the submission  result is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => test1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [url] => #1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => test2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [url] => #2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] =>title3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [url] => #3
        )

)
```

The problem is i cannot filter which url for the title1,and which for the title 2 etc..

Is there any way to have the result like this array?

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => test1,
            [url] => #1

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => test2,
            [url] => #2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => test3,
            [url] => #3
        )


  )
```

Comment: This is pretty straightforward - what have you tried? What problems have you had?

Comment: there's no php/mysql to support this question. That makes it unclear/too broad.

Comment: My problem is that i can not get the value for each title.. because the values are sending in array and not specifiy the index for which title this value is

Comment: Check my updated question.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of each field should end with `[]` For example

```
<input type="text" class="form-control " style="border-radius: 0px;" placeholder="Tittle" id="slider" name="titles[name][]">
```

This will make them available in an array in your PHP script, which you can then just iterate over, forming your query.

```
  $Q = 'insert into mytable (name, value) values ';
  $V = [];

  foreach ($titles as $idx => $title) {
    $V[] = "('".$title['name']."','".$title['value']."')";
  }
  $Q.= implode(',', $V);
```

[EDIT]

OK, make your fields look something like this

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="data[title][]">
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="data[url][]">
```

Then output it and see what you've got, and the PHP code above should help you form your query.

Comment: OK, well you changed the names of your fields while I was writing the answer, but the main thing is to end your field names with `[]`, and I think you can get the idea.

Comment: THank you for your reply.. can you please check my updated question??

Comment: I am trying to make relation with two fields url and title

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have solved my problem...

this helped a lots

<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="data[title][]">
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="data[url][]">